# How to iterate through two SUBlists in parallel?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I apologize if there is a duplicate, but I searched and could not find any topics that address my current issue.

I want to know if there is some pythonic way to iterate through two (or more) sublists in parallel. I'm already well aware of the `zip` function, so I will use it in a short example to explain what I want to do. Let's say I have the following two lists:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5,6]
```

I know that I can iterate through them simultaneously like this:

```
>>> newlist = [i+j for i,j in zip(list1, list2)]
>>> newlist
[5,7,9]
```

However, with the way my data is being handled, I would like to do something slightly different. Instead of two independent lists, my data storage looks more like this:

```
biglist = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

I know I could extract each sublist to be it's own variable, but I was moreso hoping I could do something more like this:

```
newbiglist = [i+j for i,j in zip(biglist)]
```

Where python would be able to recognize that there are two sublists in `biglist`. Does anyone know of any function that could do something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for two or more you could try this

```
[sum(i) for i in  zip(*biglist)]
```

here `i` will be iterable, so you can use any function which accepts iterable or you can write your own.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you. As an extension, what if I wanted to do some type of element wise operation, say a boolean comparison, and I didnt necessarily know the amount of sublists in `biglist`? Is this possible?

Comment: yes it is possible. instead calling sum() you call your own function which does boolean operation

Comment: I figured it was possible with my own function, but I just wanted to see if there might have been a built in way I didn't already know about. Either way, I figured it out with my own function, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
newbiglist = [i+j for i,j in zip(*biglist)]
```

The "star" or "splat" operator `*` splits the variable into its components for use as parameters.

The result then of

```
print(newbiglist)
```

is what you want:

```
[5, 7, 9]
```

Note that this will give an error if `biglist` contains something other than two lists. There are several ways to handle a differing number of lists: the answer by @crook handles that nicely, and there are other ways.

Comment: Or the functional alternative: `map(sum, zip(*biglist))`

Comment: I did not know the `*` operator could do this, thanks for the tip!